# Fundamental group of a topological group(references)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I'm studing just now at my university Algebraic Topology. I know that if $G$ is a topological group then its fundamental group is abelian. I want study the varius connections between topological groups and their fundamental groups. Can anyone suggest me some valid reference for this topic?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Topological groups* by Pontryagin.

Answer (score 0):

It is also interesting to study the fundamental groupoid of a topological group, and also to take account of the non-connected case. One reference for that is

Brown, R. and Mucuk, O. "Covering groups of nonconnected topological groups
  revisited" *Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc*.  115 (1994) 97--110. [pdf](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brown-mucuk-cov.pdf).